# How to Serialize generic foreign key In DRF

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have model with generic foreign key and I want to serialize that model.

`model.py`:

```
class AddressType(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % str(self.content_type)

class AddressBook(TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'address_book'

    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
    address_tag = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)

    # should be a generic foreign key
    address_object_type = GenericRelation(AddressType)
    address1 = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Address1',
        max_length=200,
    )
    address2 = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Address2',
        max_length=200,
    )
```

`serializer.py`:

```
class AddressBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AddressBook
        fields = ('id','uuid','address_tag','address_object_type','address1','address2')
```

How can I serialize JSON on above model?

Answer (score 16):

This case is perfectly described in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships).

So if you want to serialize `AddressType` you will need to implement something like this:

```
class ContentObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    """
    A custom field to use for the `content_object` generic relationship.
    """

    def to_representation(self, value):
        """
        Serialize tagged objects to a simple textual representation.
        """
        if isinstance(value, Bookmark):
            return 'Bookmark: ' + value.url
        elif isinstance(value, Note):
            return 'Note: ' + value.text
        raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')
```

Where `Bookmark` and `Note` are objects which may be have associated contents.

If you want to serialize `AddressBook` you can try doing something like this:

```
class AddressBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address_object_type = ContentObjectRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = AddressBook
        fields = ('id','uuid','address_tag','address_object_type','address1','address2')
```

Comment: I have done same thing but unable to succeed...would appreciate....if you could help in code...

Comment: i am getting error : "TypeError: <django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelatedObjectManager object at 0x1031ee8d0> is not JSON serializable"

Comment: all code is there except views....in views i m calling serializer...here content type would be user object...

Answer (score 9):

I'd prefer use this third party ([rest-framework-generic-relations](https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations)) as also described in [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#rest-framework-generic-relations).

```
from generic_relations.relations import GenericRelatedField

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A `TaggedItem` serializer with a `GenericRelatedField` mapping all possible
    models to their respective serializers.
    """
    tagged_object = GenericRelatedField({
        Bookmark: BookmarkSerializer(),
        Note: NoteSerializer()
    })

    class Meta:
        model = TaggedItem
        fields = ('tag_name', 'tagged_object')
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code is more structured, i.e. each app has its serializers.py, and serializer naming follows a convention (i.e. [ModelName]Serializer) you could use dynamic importing to avoid `if ... elif ... else ...` logic with a benefit of  loose coupling:

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string


class ContentObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    """
    A custom field to serialize generic relations
    """

    def to_representation(self, object):
        object_app = object._meta.app_label
        object_name = object._meta.object_name
        serializer_module_path = f'{object_app}.serializers.{object_name}Serializer'
        serializer_class = import_string(serializer_module_path)
        return serializer_class(object).data
```